# How to check if two objects are equal in java?

Tags: java, boolean, equals

Hi i'm new to java class and I am trying to compare two objects. In this case the circle consists of a point and a radius. I need to check both the point and radius if they are equal, but in my code the result is 'not equal' even though they are actually equal. sorry if my question is dumb. i've been trying to look for answers but still cant understand the problem :\

```
public class Circle{
private MyPoint point;
private float radius;
public Circle(){
    MyPoint temp = new MyPoint(0,0);
        point = temp;
        radius = 0;
    }

public Circle(MyPoint Center, float Radius){
    point = Center;
    radius = Radius;
}
public Circle(int x, int y, float Radius){
        MyPoint temp = new MyPoint(x,y);
        point = temp;
        radius = Radius;
}
public void setRadius(float Radius){
    radius = Radius;
}
public void setCenter(int x, int y){
        MyPoint temp = new MyPoint(x,y);
        point = temp;
}
public MyPoint getCenter(){
        return point;
}
public float getRadius(){
    return radius;
}
public boolean equals(Object obj){
            boolean ans = false;
            if(obj instanceof Circle){
                Circle circ = (Circle)obj;
                if(radius == (circ.radius) && point.equals( circ.point ) )
                    ans = true;
            }
            return ans;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
        Circle C1 = new Circle(10,20, 5);
        Circle C2 = new Circle(10,20, 5);
        if(C1.equals(C2))
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");

 }
```

Heres the inside of the MyPoint Class

```
public class MyPoint{
 private int x;
 private int y;
 public MyPoint(){}
 public MyPoint(int x, int y){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }
 public String toString(){
     return "("+x+","+y+")";
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the `c` in `c.equals(circ.point)`? That variable doesn't exist. We also don't know what `MyPoint` looks like. Please provide a [mcve]. (I'd also strongly advise you to follow Java naming conventions, and format your code when posting. All of this will help you to get better answers more quickly.)

Comment: oh sorry i wrote my code from scatch. ill edit my post

Comment: The first thing you should do is check to see if if the two objects under equals test are the same instance.  So `if(this == obj) {return true;}` would be a good start.

Comment: "Heres the inside of the MyPoint Class" - right, so two distinct `MyPoint` objects will never be equal to each other, but you're *asking* whether the two circles have the same center by calling equals on them. So you should implement `Equals` appropriately for `MyPoint`.

Comment: Already checked if they are both the same object and was equal, but still says not equal if I check if they have the same point

Comment: Thank you so much I already got it

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyPoint` class doesn't have an equals method, which means that `new MyPoint(1, 2)` is not equal to `new MyPoint(1, 2)` (try it!).

And, as your Circle's equals definition depends on MyPoint's equals definition in order to function - this happens.

For future reference, you can use lombok's [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) or `@Value` to automate this stuff - alternatively, your IDE can generate it for you (but this leaves ugly crud around that you must remember to update whenever you modify/add/remove fields), and in java15, Point would probably become a record, which would also remove the need to explicitly write your equals code for it.

Comment: thank you I understand now. im still new in learning java and still have a long way to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

As others point out you haven't defined an `equals()` method for `MyPoint`:

Here's one.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
       if(!(obj instanceof MyPoint)){
        return false;
       }
       MyPoint that=(MyPoint)obj;
       return (this.x==that.x && this.y==that.y);
   }
```

The posted code is (implicitly) using `Object.equals()` and `a.equalis(b)` is true iff a and b reference the same object. Not what you want.

Good practice is that if you override `equals()` you should override `hashCode()`.
If you don't then one day you might put some `Circles` in a `HashMap` and get unhappy surprises.
Don't worry about that for now but be aware if it comes up.